# C# Mainform Button Navigation childform filled in panel mainform

Tags: c#

I have a main form with main panel and filling child form in the main panel.
I want some buttons in toolbar to navigate records based on Data Table created in the child form.
Problem is I do not know how to accomplish this. 
Any code or guide to would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

So far I have done following:
**Main form**: Tree list: click link to show child form which is added in the panel in mainform

**Child form**: Form load event

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
dt = DataAccess.GetStaff(); //Recieve data from class with query executed

gridStaff.DataSource = dt;
```

How can I pass "dt" to public method then code the "Next" button in toolbar in the main form navigate. Next record is based on "dt" datatable (Is it possible?) or can I pass grid to public to navigate it. (I used extragrid devexpress).
Or Show way to accomplish that issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link to learn a bit about datagrids and navigators:
[BindSourceBindingNavCS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/BindSourceBindingNavCS.aspx)

You can also watch this video [SmartClient: Data GridView Getting Started](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=13402)

After that article and that movie you should have a basic understanding about which controls and objects to use.